# I cannot auto create table from hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate project and I want to auto create table. And if a table is already created then I add a new field in the Entity class then I want to create a new field in the table without deleting data of the table.I'm giving my source in the below.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>

  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

  <mapping class="Inventory" package="com.mycompany.testhibernate"/>


   </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
```

EntityClass

```
     package com.mycompany.testhibernate;

     import java.io.Serializable;
     import javax.persistence.Entity;
     import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
     import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
     import javax.persistence.Id;

     @Entity
    public class Inventory implements Serializable {
       private Integer id;
       private String itemName;
       private String itemNote;
       private Integer quantity;

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
       public int getId() {
        return id;
       }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
      }

   public String getItemName() {
    return this.itemName;
   }

   public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
   }

   public String getItemNote() {
    return itemNote;
   }

   public void setItemNote(String itemNote) {
    this.itemNote = itemNote;
  }

   public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  public int getQuantity() {
    return this.quantity;
  }    


   }
```

Comment: which mysql version do u used?

Comment: mysql version 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with this option?

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Should update your DDL according to your beans

> hbm2ddl.auto update :
>
> If the value is update then hibernate checks for the table and
>   columns. If table doesn’t exist then it creates a new table and if a
>   column doesn’t exist it creates new column for it.

Also change the property to:

```
<mapping class="com.mycompany.testhibernate.Inventory"/>
```

Comment: I also tried by <property       name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> but it does not work

Comment: I guess your mapping tag is wrong, should be <mapping class="com.mycompany.testhibernate.Inventory"/>

Comment: public static void main( String[] args ) {
            AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
           config.addAnnotatedClass(Inventory.class );
           config.configure();
           new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
    }     When I run the following code from entity class I can create table in the database and delete the existing data from the table.but I do not want this.

Comment: Use SchemaUpdate update = new SchemaUpdate( configuration );
        update.execute(...)

Comment: thanks to cralfaro,but your code will be :  new SchemaUpdate(config).execute(true, true) excepting of  new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);;

Comment: @Riyad yes in the comment i ddint give all details, is hard to read code in a comment, then i just tried to point you to use SchemaUpdate class